# Why do complex analysis and complex geometry exhibit a sort of "arithmetic" behavior?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

That is going to be a rather vague question, but as I stated in the title, why do complex analysis and complex geometry seem to exhibit a sort of "arithmetic" behavior, contrary to real analysis and real differential geometry?

I am referring to facts like complex tori having as moduli space $\mathbb H/PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ while real tori are all diffeomorphic, or the relation between complex analysis and number theory in general.

Is there a deeper reason for that? After all, at a first glance real and complex analysis are built on the derivative, which is constructed in the same way in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, only relying on completeness as metric spaces and field operations (as far as I know). Only difference (although a relevant one) being that one of them is algebraically closed, while the other one is not; again, as far as I know.

Apologies again for this not-so-well-asked question.

Comment: The "discrete" nature from the complex tori just comes from the fact that a tori is specified by a grid in $\mathbb{C}$ of the form $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ and $2$ grids are the same of the they are related by transformation $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. But I love the question! +1 The diffeomorphism for tori is not necessarily biholomorphic and that is why we need to compute the moduli space with a bit effort.

Comment: Complex differentiation is more rigidly defined than general or multivariable differentiation as complex differentiable functions must obey the Cauchy-Reimann equations.  This means that they are much nicer.

Comment: @user317176 I would say it is more rigidly defined because $\Bbb C$-linear maps $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is a much more restrictive condition than $\Bbb R$-linear maps $\Bbb R^{2}\to\Bbb R^{2}$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations merely quantify this difference. But that's a philosophical matter.

Comment: I find this question intriguing as well. Tori lead to elliptic functions and these lead to modular forms, which have very rich arithmetic properties and applications.

Comment: @LukasHeger You were correct and I did interpret the question in the wrong way, on second thought. So I'll just comment with a link to some interesting lectures on the topic: https://youtu.be/eX6yNYiy-WA?list=PLCe-H2N8-ny7NtxoSNp8DTP3ic64MuY7G&t=393 To the OP, I would request that he clarify his question before a proper answer can be given. It is not clear (at least to me) what the example is meant to illustrate. The appearance of non-trivial moduli? The appearance of an arithmetic group? I do not know.

Comment: There are many connections between number theory/arithmetic geometry and complex geometry: modular/automorphic forms, Shimura varieties, dessins d'enfants/Belyi maps on Riemann surfaces, the fact that a lot of functions from analytic NT are holmorphic/meromorphic, especially zeta functions, the Weil conjectures which propose (among other things) a connection between the number of solutions of an equation mod $p^n$ and the topology of the solutions over $\Bbb C$ and probably much more. The abundance of such connections is striking, but I don't expect a single "deeper" reason to explain all that

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that could be of course part of the answer but thinking about it, the ring of holomorphic functions isn't a domain either when the underlying space is not connected. But anyway as someone else pointed out my question it's probably too much philosophical and a precise answer cannot be given. I'm still glad for all the comments i received, I will try to think about them, maybe I'll try to ask this question again in more precise terms in the future. :)

Comment: Your example of moduli of tori does have a "deeper" explanation or at least generalisation: tori are 1-d abelian varieties and moduli spaces of abelian varieties (perhaps with extra structure) are Shimura varieties. Shimura varieties are very arithmetic objects, they are defined over a number field, among other things. In a Shimura datum a lot of arithmetic information determines a Shimura variety